# Windows Phone 8.0/coding4fun v1.6.1/InputPrompt disappears on Windows 10 Phones

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10

I have an app, written for Windows Phone 8.0 with Coding4Fun version 1.6.1. When I run the app on Windows 10 Phone, Coding4Fun InputPrompt disappears when the keyboard appears. This happens only on device, in all emulators everything is ok. Any idea, what should I do?

Comment: Log an issue in their repo: https://github.com/Coding4FunProjects/Coding4FunToolkit

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by upgrading the 8.0 project to 8.1 Silverlight project in VS2013. 8.1 Silverlight app runs now correctly also in Windows 10 phone.